# How to sort a big file of sentences with variable length?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ranking

Suppose I have a file of many lines of string, how to rank the lines of string in lexicographic order?

**Details:**

- The file size is about **32GB**ytes;
- Each line can be regarded as one sentence, which contains variable numbers of words separated by spaces, i.e. the length of each line is not fixed;
- Each word contains only ASCII characters;
- I have only **8 GB**ytes of memory but unlimited disk space;

What I can figure out is an external merge sort, is there any better idea for this specified problem?

Comment: An external merge sort sounds like a pretty good option. You might also consider splitting up the file according to (say) the first character -- first make a little histogram to figure out how to split it -- and then sorting each of the resulting subfiles and concatenating them. (You might either actually write the subfiles, or else generate each on the fly by a separate pass through the big 32GB file.)

Comment: It will be hard to do better than `sort < infile > outfile`.  GNU `sort` (and possibly the Windows version) automatically handle files much larger than memory, using efficient multipass merges as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between file size and the memory is not that big, therefore I would suggest to split file into more smaller files based on first letter - or if it is not enough, by the first two letters.

Then you can sort each of them with quicksort and save it and when then they are sorted, you can put them back together.

It would be still O(N) I/O operations and O(n*log(N)) CPU operations.

PS : External merge sort is also good way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you detailedly describe how the split works? Since we have variable length of line, I think it might happen that hashing by letters leads to an overflow. For example if we have 10% the number of lines which starts with the letters 'aa' and totally they occupy 50% of the space (suppose they are very long 'aa blabla bla bla...' sentences).

Comment: @idailylife - this can happen, but it is very unlikely. If you are making a one-time import, you can just try it and if it does not fall on memory, you are fine. If it falls, you can change the behaviour. If you want general-solution, you can always keep splitting the files that are too big to more and more prefix letters (you will see the size of each file before you load it).